# Как вернуть ID после сочетания клавиш?

Tags: javascript

На веб-странице есть кнопка:

```js
var mute = document.getElementById("mute");
      
        window.addEventListener("keydown", Sound, false); 
       
        function Sound(event) {
         var e = event.keyCode;
            if (e == 77) {
                mute.setAttribute("id", "unmute");
            }
         else {
          mute.setAttribute("id", "mute");
         } 
        }
```

```html
<button id="mute">Кнопка</button>
```

После нажатия клавиш `Ctrl + M` скрипт ниже у кнопки меняет id на `unmute`.

```
var mute = document.getElementById("mute");

        window.addEventListener("keydown", Sound, false); 

        function Sound(event) {
            var e = event.keyCode;
            if (e == 77) {
                mute.setAttribute("id", "unmute");
            }
            else {
                mute.setAttribute("id", "mute");
            }   
        }
```

Как при повторном сочетании клавиш `Ctrl + M` вернуть кнопке id `mute`?

Comment: id это уникальный идентификатор элемента ! Зачем его менять ? добавте себе какойнибуть `data-state="mute/unmute"` и меняйте уже его!

Comment: А вы уверены, что именно при нажатии `Ctrl+M` у вас `id` у кнопки изменяется?

Comment: Cheg - абсолютно уверен!

Comment: @Viher и совсем ничего страшного что `77` это код клавиши `M` ?

Comment: @Viher очень интересно, ведь нажатие `Ctrl` в коде никак не отслеживается

Comment: function Sound(e) {
      var evt = window.event? event : e
      if (evt.keyCode == 77 && evt.ctrlKey) mute.setAttribute("id", "unmute");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var mute = document.querySelector('.mute');

window.addEventListener("keydown", Sound, false);

function Sound(event) {
  if ((event.ctrlKey) && (event.keyCode == 77)) {
    if (mute.getAttribute('id') == 'mute') {
      mute.setAttribute('id', 'unmute');
    } else {
      mute.setAttribute('id', 'mute');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="mute" class="mute">Кнопка</button>
```